# Зачем используются вместе #pragma once и header guards?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, макросы

Всем доброго времени суток!
Изучая стандартные библиотеки в Visual Studio 2019 меня удивили подобные строчки:

```
// string standard header

#pragma once
#ifndef _STRING_
#define _STRING_


// vector standard header

#pragma once
#ifndef _VECTOR_
#define _VECTOR_
```

Я думал, что прагма и header guards взаимозаменяемы и выполняют ту же функцию - пресекают дублирование кода.
С какой целью их использовали вместе?

Comment: я знаю только один хороший ответ - для перестраховки. И у одного, и у другого способа есть небольшой шанс, что он не сработает. А так, есть шанс, что мы обойдем это

Comment: Ну а вдруг будет использовано на компиляторе, который `#pragma once` не понимает? :) А скорее всего — просто старый код остался, не мешает — и слава богу. А может, эти `_VECTOR_` и т.п. используются (или, может, будут когда-то использованы)  в других заголовках для других целей...

Comment: Ну если честно, то pragma one не стандартизирован, хотя и поддерживается кучей компиляторов. Думаю, что когда модули войдут в полную силу, необходимость выбора pragma once ищи define guard уйдет сама собой

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь!
В https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once сказано:

> Можно использовать обе команды, #pragma once и include guards, для
> написания переносимого кода, что также может принести выгоду от
> применения #pragma once при оптимизации (если компилятор её
> поддерживает)

Хотя здесь https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170 сказано:

> There's no advantage to use of both the include guard idiom and
> #pragma once in the same file.